# Grails and MySQL partitioning

Tags: mysql, grails, partitioning

I'm developing a Grails application to replace a desktop database application which has been running for many years (in various forms since 1991, in fact). There is a Sale table which contains sales going back 25 years. What I'm interested in most of the time, though, is just a set of sales which are still active, dating back maybe a month or so. I don't want searching etc on these to be dragged down by the huge amount of older data. I do, however, need to access that older data in some places, for archive searches.

One obvious way to deal with this would be to have a separate domain class, say ArchivedSale, with the same properties as Sale, and once a Sale is no longer active (data has been posted to accounts, say) I could create an ArchivedSale from it and delete the original. This does, though, strike me as falling foul of the Don't Repeat Yourself principle - I have to make any domain class changes in both places, which doesn't feel like a good idea.

Maybe I don't need to concern myself about performance, though, if I use MySQL partitioning? I could have all sales with a date of 2015 and earlier in one partition and everything else in another, which would nicely resolve any performance issues. I've never used partitioning before, though, and reading up on it I'm a little concerned as it seems that the primary key needs to be used in the partitioning criteria, and I know I can't really play around with the MySQL primary keys as they're critical to the way Grails works.

I wonder has anyone done anything similar to the above with Grails and can give me some tips? Or, failing that, is there another good solution to my problem which I may have overlooked?

Comment: If suitable indexes are available and being used, and the SQL has been tuned, then MySQL partitioning may improve performance of some queries, in some very specific circumstances. (The queries have to be *specifically* written with predicates that allow the MySQL optimizer to do "partition pruning".) But where partitioning really shines is managing large volumes of data, vastly improving efficiency of some operations (such as emptying an entire partition), and makes for more manageable sets. Partitioning in and of itself is not a magic bullet for improved performance.

Comment: Another possibility is to have two datasources one that does not get manipulated once set and one that you keep clean up to date information. Carefully does it to manage how you manage it but this would mean you write transacation once to two db's. This be the answer  don't repeat yourself

Comment: Is it possible to use two datasources for the same domain class?

Comment: sure it is static mapping={datasources(['myotherDatasource','DEFAULT']) } this then generates the  domain class on two different databses default being main datasource and myotherDataSource as stated. You will need to research it as in how to configure and use it. There are other complications with it but it can be done @myusername to get my attention othewise i won't get a marker

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be onto something with separate tables, but I'd implement it with inheritance and table per subclass.

http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/guide/GORM.html#inheritanceInGORM

Comment: This looks like a great solution to me. I would have a Sale class and and ArchivedSale subclass, with, as you suggest, table per subclass strategy. That should take care of any performance issues nicely, I would imagine.